# Web3j gets stack underflow error with Ganache

Tags: java, ethereum, remix, ganache, web3-java

I'm experiencing the error "Error processing transaction request: VM Exception while processing transaction: stack underflow" basically with any contract. I'm using Ganache v2.1.2 and Web3j 4.5.15. Same thing with Ganache CLI v6.9.1 (ganache-core: 2.10.2). I'm able to deploy the contract with Remix IDE and Metamask plug-in without any issue.

The Java code:

```
public class contractCR
  {

    static class OSCGasProvider implements ContractGasProvider
      {     

        public OSCGasProvider(){}

        @Override
        public BigInteger getGasPrice(String string)
          {            
           return Convert.toWei("1", Convert.Unit.GWEI).toBigInteger();             
          }       

        @Override
        public BigInteger getGasLimit(String string)
          {
            return BigInteger.valueOf(3000000);
          }

        @Override
        public BigInteger getGasPrice()
          {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
          }

        @Override
        public BigInteger getGasLimit()
          {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
          }

      }

    public static void main (String args[])
      {
        System.out.println("Connecting to Ethereum ...");
        Web3j web3 = Web3j.build(new HttpService("http://localhost:7545"));
        System.out.println("Successfuly connected to Ethereum");
        try 
          {
            // web3_clientVersion returns the current client version.
            Web3ClientVersion clientVersion = web3.web3ClientVersion().send();
            Credentials credentials=Credentials.create(privateKey);
            Faucet osc = Faucet.deploy(web3, credentials, new OSCGasProvider()).send();
            String contractAddress = osc.getContractAddress();
            System.out.println("The contract address is: "+contractAddress);
           } 
        catch (IOException ex)
          {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error while sending json-rpc requests", ex);
          }
        catch (Exception ex)
          {
              System.out.println(ex.toString());
          }     
      }
}
```

The simple Faucet contract:

```
// Version of Solidity compiler this program was written for
pragma solidity ^0.5.12;

// Our first contract is a faucet!
contract Faucet {

    address payable owner_addr; //the owner address

    //initialize the contract
    constructor() public 
    {
      owner_addr=msg.sender;
    }

    //contract destructor
    modifier owner_allowed
    {
      require (msg.sender==owner_addr, "Only contract owner is allowed to call this function");    
      _;
    }

    function destroy() public owner_allowed
    {
      selfdestruct(owner_addr);
    }

    // Give out ether to anyone who asks
    function withdraw(uint withdraw_amount) public
     {
        // Limit withdrawal amount
        require(withdraw_amount <= 100000000000000000); //0.1ether
        // Send the amount to the address that requested it
        msg.sender.transfer(withdraw_amount);
    }

    // Accept any incoming amount
    function () external payable {} //fallback or default function

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally I figured out the problem.  Web3j-cli does not accept the binary provided by Remix-IDE, but only the field "binary". Giving as input a file containing only  binary data to Web3j-cli produced the correct wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's one Ganache related issue https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli/issues/465

Per my test, it could work well my local Ganache 2.1.2

Comment: So, I guess there is no solution today.

Comment: I'm not sure wether you have tried below actions:
1. restart ganache
2. try different ganache version
3. use one private geth node instead of ganache

Your code could work well, no need stuck on ganache per my opinion

Answer (score 0):

I got the same *stack underflow* error when deploying a Vyper contract to ganache with *Web3j*.  The exact cause was, when Vyper outputs the contract bytecode (A.K.A. binary), it adds `0x` to front and `\n` to the end.   To fix the problem, I wrote a shell script that strips the unwanted chars from the bytecode.

It's worth noting that, the contract deployed successfully, *with no changes*, when deployed with *Truffle* or *Web3.py*.  So, the problem really comes down to whether the compiler output format matches the format the deployer utility wants.